# Confusion about loss of root when solving trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry, roots

This is a solved example from my textbook: $\DeclareMathOperator{\csc}{cosec}$

> **Ex. 11:** Find the general solution of $\cot x + \tan x = 2\csc x$.
>
> **Solution:** As given
>   \begin{align}
> && \cot x + \tan x &= 2\csc x \\
> &\therefore& \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} + \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} &= \frac{2}{\sin x} \\
> &\therefore& \frac{\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x}{\sin x\cos x} &= \frac{2}{\sin x} \\
> &\therefore& \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x &= 2\cos x \\
> &\therefore& 2\cos x &= 1 \\
> &\therefore& \cos x &= \frac{1}{2} \\
> &\therefore& \cos x &= \cos \frac{\pi}{3}
> \end{align}
>   $\therefore$ the required general solution $x = 2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

As you can see, they have cancelled $\sin x$ in the denominator. Is that causing loss of a root here? Is $x = n\pi$ a solution?

Comment: When the $\sin{x}$ was cancelled, it was assumed that $\sin{x} \neq 0$. The first equation is not defined for $\sin{x} =0$, so it doesn't change anything. $x = n\pi$ is not a solution; on the contrary, the expression in the beginning is not even defined for those values.

Comment: @MattiP. I made such a silly mistake  .. I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: @MattiP.Soo.. when does canceling a term lead to loss of a root (in 0 to 2π for trig. eqns.) -- only when the term is in the numerator? Or is that thing only for polynomial equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with the equation $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{2}{\sin x}.$

This equation is only defined for values of $x$ such that $\cos x \ne 0 \ne \sin x$.

Comment: How could I forget to check the domain  ... thank you!